# PHP class property contains child of a parent but was shown error due to parent class not containing method from child

Tags: php

I am learning OOP right now and I have a property that specifies what class it should be.

```
class Controller{
  public ?Model $model;
}

class LoginModel extends Model{
  public function login(){}
}
```

Now, I want to load a class that is an inheritance of Model but contains a unique method not from Model. That causes the lint to think that there is an error in the code. Is there a way to fix the issue from Controller->model?

```
$controller = new Controller();
$controller->model = new LoginModel();
echo $controller->model->login();
```

I know that one way is we can change Model to LoginModel but that would be tedious if there are a lot of different controllers with different model designed to do different things.

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: The error is the linting says that login is not defined due to class Model not containing a method called login except for LoginModel. And as you can see from Controller, the property $model has a type Model and when I assign to it, I use LoginModel which is extended from Model. But I need to call out the method login which does not exists in Model hence the linting issue.

Answer (score 1):

consider this example

```
class Controller
{
    public ?Model $model;
}

class Model { }

class LoginModel extends Model
{
    public function login() { }
}

class LogoutModel extends Model { }


$controller = new Controller();

$controller->model = new LoginModel();
$controller->model->login(); //This works 

$controller->model = new LogoutModel();
$controller->model->login(); //This doesn't works
```

The lint is *saying* that you cannot assure that there will be a `login()` to call. So unless you'll have a `login()` method in all models, in which case you can define an abstract or interface, otherwise since it can fail it will show you the error.

PS: there is a way around it, but I wouldn't recommend it for regular use.

```
if($controller->model instanceof LoginModel) 
{
    $controller->model->login(); //This works
}
```

Comment: Well technically, the lint error still persists regardless it contains the if statement or not.